# For a quantum system with two contacts, how does one construct the contact hamiltonian for NEGF transport?

Tags: hamiltonian, nanoscience, quantum-transport

For context, I have been going through Supriyo Datta's NEGF course, slides, lecture material, and have been learning how to simulate quantum transport in his formalism.

For simplicity, consider a 1D-in-x chain of atoms.

Question: How does one represent the lead hamiltonian, for the sake of calculating $G_{l(r)}, \Sigma_{l(r)}?$

for the simple 1D chain, I end up with an expression H(k) with bands that we expect. But, this is not very useful for the 1-eigenstate-per-k representation of the lead's greens functions, as $G_{lead}$ would then result with $G(E)_{lead} = (E\hat{I} - \hat{H}(k))$. Supriyo skirts around this by solving for k(E) which is fortunately exactly solvable for the 1D chain. However, this is rather intractable for a more complex material. Should I be integrating over $k_x$ to get the transport?

Surely this is not done in the case of QuantumATK, Wannier90, etc, which already have enough dimensions to integrate over to calculate transport (kx,ky for a periodic system). I recall that transport was swept in E (perhaps E(k)?) in most calculations.

I have spent the last few months building up tight-binding models for different systems, and have some H(k) functions that return a matrix in the $|site\rangle \otimes |orbital\rangle \otimes |spin\rangle $ hilbert space. Alternatively, I can prune the hoppings outside of the supercell and just consider a slab of my material and generate a finite H.

So I think I know how to hook up the different leads and generate the other terms. And also most of the NEGF formalism after. But this particular stumbling block has been very opaque to me over the past few days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out.

Supposing one wishes to perform transport in z. I believe (?) one does not construct the full $H_{l,r}(kx,ky,kz)$, but instead constructs a slab H(kx,ky) and constructs an H_r and H_l that connects the ends of the slab to each other with the relevant hopping parameters. Defining $H_{coupling} = H_l + H_r$, then one can self consistently calculate the self-energy for the "bulk" of H(kx,ky):

$\Sigma_{bulk}(kx,ky) = H_c(kx,ky)(E+i\eta - H(kx,ky) -\Sigma_{bulk})^{-1}H_c^{\dagger}(kx,ky)$

Then the self energy for the infinite contacts goes as

$\Sigma_{l,r}(kx,ky) = H_{l,r}(kx,ky)G^{R}_{bulk}(kx,ky)H_{l,r}^{\dagger}(kx,ky) = H_{l,r}(kx,ky)(E+i\eta - H(kx,ky) -\Sigma_{bulk})^{-1}H_{l,r}^{\dagger}(kx,ky)$

One then changes the basis to connect to the central device, with a list of vectors P that determine where the sites permute to:

$\Sigma_{l,r} = P*H_{l,r}(kx,ky)(E+i\eta - H(kx,ky) -\Sigma_{bulk})^{-1}H_{l,r}^{\dagger}(kx,ky)*P'$

This is consistent with Supriyo Datta's guide, and agglomerated from a few sources I've found if anyone is interested.